# Mongo DB: Message exceeds allowed max message size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, docker, web, docker-compose

¡Hi! I've just developed RoR application to work with MongoDB and works fine. I tried few http requests to the app with postman, also worked fine!

When I deployed the app using Docker, I got a MongoDB error that follows after any request:

> MONGODB | Message exceeds allowed max message size. The max is 50331648.
>   ms_notifications_1     | 2017-09-29 21:16:48 +0000: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): # Puma::HttpParserError: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.

I'll be very thankful If anybody have the solution for this error. Thanks!

My compose file:

```
 version: '2' 
 services:
  ms_notifications_db:
   image: mongo:latest
   container_name: "rancher-node1" `

   environment:
    - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
    - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
   volumes:
    - ./data/db:/data/db 
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --smallfiles `

  ms_notifications:
   build: .
   command: bash -c " rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle
    exec rails db:migrate && bundle exec rails s -p 3007 -b '0.0.0.0'"
   ports:
    - "3007:3007"
   depends_on:
    - ms_notifications_db
```

Comment: Post your compose file

Comment: Don't disable Mongo logs using `MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null` because we want to see what is happening in this case

Comment: I've disabled it but cannot find any mongo dir inside container. I've tried /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log but only exists locally not in container. :) @TarunLalwani

Comment: Okie so I did find some information for you on how to debug. Change your command to `command: mongod --smallfiles --profile 2`. Run `docker-compose exec ms_notifications_db mongo` in one terminal and access the app and reproduce the issue. Now execute `db.system.profile.find().pretty()` in the mongo terminal we opened. You will see details about every single query that was fired. See what is wrong there